# How to create query in django with query in url, and return the filtered result based on the url?

Tags: python, html, django

I found several similar answers, but I could not solve the problem (maybe I searched wrong) anyway.

I'm trying to do the following:

- Filter a result by getting the value of "q" where is the input containing the value to search
- Add the "q" value in the url, like "/search?q=test"
  Copy the url above and from there get the filtered result

My problem so far is:

- The value of "q" is only added in the url after another search, ie the url contains "q" with the previous search value, which is bad
- I can not access the url and have the results filtered, since when I enter this url, a new request object with no value for "q" is created, so I get a ValueError

So far what I've done is:

template

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'blog:post_search' %}?q={{ query }}" class="form-inline">
    <div class="md-form my-0">
        <input name="q" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-white btn-sm my-0" type="submit">GO</button>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ....
    path('search', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
]
```

views.py

```
def post_search(request):
    template = "blog/post_search.html"
    query = request.POST.get('q')
    if query:
        posts = Post.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    else:
        posts = Post.objects.all()

    context = {'posts': posts, 'query': query}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `POST` and `GET` methods here. Query parameters in the url are typically only used with get requests.

So in your form, you can change this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'blog:post_search' %}?q={{ query }}" class="form-inline">
```

to

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:post_search' %}" class="form-inline">
```

The default method for a html form is GET, and named inputs will automatically be included in the action url by the browser when you submit the form. So you should not have a querystring in the from action attribute `action='/search'` is enough.

In the view you access url parameters from `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
```

Comment: i love u bro <3
Now I've seen that the query is automatically added to the url when the method is GET. Do you have any study recommendations to better understand these things?